# SQLAlchemy Subtract 2 Values in Same Column Differentiated By Another Column ID

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am looking to make a query that will look at the "reading" column of a table, and return the difference of the average readings over the past hour with another column (called height) id of 1 or 2.

Essentially, make average of all readings over past hour with height value of 1. Make average of all readings over past hour with height value of 2, and subtract the two.

How can I do this in one query in sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be want you want because I don't know sqlalchemy, but a raw Postgresql SQL query to achieve could be

```
SELECT 
AVG(CASE WHEN height = 2 THEN reading ELSE NULL END) - 
AVG(CASE WHEN height = 1 THEN reading ELSE NULL END)
FROM table
WHERE reading_time >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 HOUR')
```

This makes use of the fact that NULL values are excluded from the AVG aggregate function.